# For aninhado paralelo VBA Excel

Tags: excel-vba

Estou realizando um `For` dentro outro `For`, onde corre por coluna, encontra a célula e copia, no outro `For` corre coluna também e cola numa range. Porém, o código está realizando todo um `For` primeiro para depois realizar o outro e preciso que  execute os dois (copiando e colando).

Podem me ajudar? Abaixo o código que realizei...

```
SUB ()

Set Cop = Workbooks(Arq)
L = Cop.Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Range("J1048576").End(xlUp).Row

   For w = 15 To 135

        If Cells(6, w) <> "" Then
           Cells(6, w).Copy

        End If

            For y = 18 To 138

                If Cells(8, y) = "" Then
                   Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Range(Cells(8, y), Cells(L, y)).PasteSpecial xlValues

                   w = w + 4
                   y = y + 4

                End If


        If w = 136 And y = 139 Then

            Exit For
    Exit For

            Else
                w = w - 1
                y = y - 1

        End If

        Next y
    Next w

END SUB
```

Comment: O que você realmente deseja? Poderia colocar imagens? Pois o seu código mostra que você copia uma célula de uma coluna não vazia e tenta colar numa range que vai da linha 8 até a última linha da coluna J

Answer (score 0):

### Um for loop

Não é necessário Utilizar o copy/paste, pois é mais lento do que simplesmente escrever, para 100 linhas é viável. Porém para mais de 20000 linhas pode se tornar lento.

As ações da planilha podem ser alcançadas somente com um for loop, sem a necessidade de nested for loops.

```
Sub teste()

Set Cop = Workbooks(Arq)
L = Cop.Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Range("J1048576").End(xlUp).Row

   For w = 15 To 135 Step 4
        y = w + 3
        If Cells(6, w) <> "" And Cells(8, y)="" Then
           Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Range(Cells(8, y), Cells(L, y)) = Cells(6, w)
        End If

        If w = 136 And y = 139 Then
            Exit For
            Else
                w = w - 1
                y = y - 1
        End If
    Next w

End Sub
```

- w = w + 4 pode ser substituído por Step 4
- Como a relação de w com y é de y=w+3, o outro for pode ser retirado
- O If pode conter mais de uma condição, utilizando operadores como o `E(And)`.

Obs.: Não entendi para que serve esta parte:

```
    If w = 136 And y = 139 Then
        Exit For
        Else
            w = w - 1
            y = y - 1
    End If
```

### Usando Copy/Paste

```
Set Cop = Workbooks(Arq)

   For w = 15 To 135 Step 4
    ultimaLinha = Cop.Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Cells(Cop.Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Rows.Count, w).End(xlUp).Row
        y = w + 3
        If Cells(6, w) <> "" And Cells(8, y) = "" Then
            Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Cells(6, w).Copy
            Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Range(Cells(8, y), Cells(L, y)).PasteSpecial xlValues
        End If
    Next w
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel, 
Deu certo e agradeço muito pela ajuda!!! 
Apenas realizei uma pequena alteração, pois realmente preciso copiar de uma célula e colar numa range.

Apenas essa parte precisei alterar...

```
If Cells(6, w) <> "" And Cells(8, y) = "" Then
   Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Cells(6, w).Copy
   Sheets("Consolidado_Vendas_TFN").Range(Cells(8, y), Cells(L, y)).PasteSpecial xlValues
End If
```